# Haskell, List as input for a function, How?

Tags: haskell

I've been given the following question in my coursework;

Define a function

```
flatten :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
```

that flattens a list of pairs of characters and digits to a string. For example:

```
flatten [('a',5),('b',4),('c',2)]
"a5b4c2"
flatten [('d',9),('d',3)]
"d9d3"
```

My problem is that whenever I attempt to define this function i get a type error relating the the `[(Char, Int)]` input. For example;

> ```
> Couldn't match type '(Char, Int)' with '[Char]'
> Expected type: [[Char]]
> Actual type: [(Char, Int)]
> ```

I've tried more ways of writing this definition in more ways than I can count, so I don't have any particular code to show, or any particular error ( I kept getting different ones...so many). All i have so far is;

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten [] = []
```

i figure my next line should go something like;

```
flatten ???? = concat (????)
```

but I have no idea what to put in place of these question marks and Google search/class notes give no examples to follow. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is clear that in the case the list is **not** empty, it is of the form `((ca,cb):cs)` with `ca` the `Char`, `cb` the `Int` and `cs` the remainder of the list `[(Char,Int)]`.

In that case we can simply construct a string for that sequence `ca:(show cb)` with [`show :: Show a => a -> String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:show) we convert an integer to its `String` counterpart. Next we concatenate the flattening of remainder of the list to that string, so:

```
flatten ((ca,cb):cs) = ca:(show cb ++ flatten cs)
```

Or in full:

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten [] = []
flatten ((ca,cb):cs) = ca:(show cb ++ flatten cs)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we try to create a `String` from a `(Char, Int)`. If we can do that we've almost done, since we can do that for all `(Char, Int)`. So let's transform a single `(Char, Int)`:

```
flattenSingle :: (Char, Int) -> String
flattenSingle (c, i) = c : show i
```

Now, we need to do that for all entries:

```
flattenAll :: [(Char, Int)] -> [String]
flattenAll xs = map flattenSingle xs
```

And last, but not least, we need to `concat` the `[String]` (which is a `[[Char]]`) to a `String` (which is a `[Char]`):

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten xs = concat (flattenAll xs)
```

And we're done. How did we do that? Well, we've started with a much easier problem, namely how to get a single `String` from a `(Char, Int)`, and used that to get our result.

Here's everything in a single function:

```
flatten = concat . map flattenSingle
  where
    flattenSingle (c, i) = c : show i
```

Since `concat . map f` is often used, there's a function for that, called `concatMap`:

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten = concatMap flattenSingle
  where
    flattenSingle (c, i) = c : show i
```

Comment: + for the `concatMap` my original idea was `flatten = concat.map (\(c,i) -> c : show i)`

Answer (score 2):

Let’s think about what goes into `flatten` and what comes out of it.
`flatten`, takes a list of pairs of type: `(Char, Int)` and produces a `[Char]`; it produces a list from an existing list. Does this ring a bell?

```
flatten xs = [ c | (char, int) <- xs, c <-[char] ++ show int]
```

We can sequentially deconstruct each pair in the given list; for each pair, we turn each component into a string so we can concatenate them. Now we have a string for each pair, we just need to take each character out to produce the final string.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use `foldl` to make your intention very clear:

```
a=[('a',5),('b',4),('c',2)]
f b (x,y)=b++[x]++(show y)   
result=foldl f "" a
```

Or you can make it a one-liner:

Solution 1:

```
foldl (\b (x,y)->b++[x]++(show y)) "" a
```

Solution 2:

```
concat $ map (\(x,y)->[x]++show y) a
```

Solution 3: (Being more efficient compared to solution 1)

```
foldr (\(x,y) b->b++[x]++(show y)) "" a
```

Comment: foldr would be acceptable here (though concatMap is better, as mentioned elsewhere). foldl, however, is a poor choice. It is quite expensive to use in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

```
flatten = mconcat. map (\(c,i) -> [c] ++ show i)
```